# Decrement loop in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been trying to change my loop to decrement rather than increment. Nothing I have tried is working, please can someone help me.

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
   #code
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Comment: The problem is you're not understanding what `each` does. It traverses the contents of your `@orders` array, from the first element to the last. To walk that list backwards you have to reverse the list somehow. The Array documentation covers that nicely.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Array#reverse_each](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#reverse_each-instance_method)

> Same as Array#each, but traverses self in reverse order.

try the below :

```
<% @orders.reverse_each do |order| %>
   #code
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is even better than `@orders.reverse.each` as well, in case someone considered that. At least on MRI, `reverse_each` is implemented as a loop that counts from the end of the array to the beginning, while `reverse.each` creates a new array and then loops over that (so, `reverse_each` is roughly O(n), while `reverse.each` is roughly O(2n) (disclaimer: I don't actually know big O notation, so this may be completely wrong)).

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider

```
@orders = Order.where(whatever: 'something').order('created_at DESC')
```

Above, we sorted the `@orders` by the `created_at` field. You could sort using whichever field you like. Then you can iterate normally

```
<% @orders.each do |order| %>
  yay!
<% end %>
```